# The last line in my console is always >test no matter what I run

Tags: r, output

When I run code, I see the output in my console but the last line always reads >test.

I had a vector named test, but I removed it from my environment using rm() but the bottom line of output remains unchanged. I'm not sure why this remains there.

Comment: Welcome to `stackoverflow`; kindly include your code and some sample data in your question, so that someone responding to your question may first be able to reproduce the situation.

Comment: Would attach screen shot to the console ?

Comment: Hit the <ESC> key.

Answer (score 1):

You likely just had typed test into console and never hit enter, now when send lines from a source file they run, and reverts back to your un-ran line in the console. Try putting your cursor on the console line, deleting the test text and hit enter.